# Syntax WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update `row 3(id=8)` in my table here [image]

Using the following query:

```
UPDATE player_ban 
   SET until = Now(), 
       unbanned_by = "MrSnare", 
       unbanned_reason = "test", 
       unbanned_date = Now() 
 WHERE name = "MCYasman" 
     & unbanned_by = NULL 
     & until > NOW();
```

The query is running but no rows are being updated.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would alter your query to use `AND` instead of the `&` and `unbanned_by IS NULL`. So the query will be:

```
UPDATE player_ban 
SET until = Now(), 
    unbanned_by = "MrSnare", 
    unbanned_reason = "test", 
    unbanned_date = Now() 
WHERE name = "MCYasman" 
  AND unbanned_by IS NULL 
  AND until > now();
```

An value will never be `= null`, you have to use `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

dont use `&` , use `AND` instead

```
 WHERE name = "MCYasman" AND unbanned_by IS NULL AND until > now();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your unbanned_by check to use "is null" instead of "= NULL". Like so.

```
UPDATE player_ban SET until = Now(), unbanned_by = "MrSnare", unbanned_reason = "test", unbanned_date = Now() WHERE name = "MCYasman" & unbanned_by is NULL & until > now();
```

NULL is not equal to itself in SQL.

```
> select null = null, null is null, null is not null;
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
| null = null | null is null | null is not null |
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
|        NULL |            1 |                0 |
+-------------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: you're right, but this is not the only mistake in his request